# Vue.js pass data between routes

Tags: vue.js

I started working on small project using **vue.js**, i have a client list in **(index.vue)** and i would like to receive the client id in the **(profile.vue)**

my index.vue code :

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'summary', params: { id: contact.id }}">{{ contact.name }}</router-link>
```

how can i receive the **contact.id** in the **(profile.vue)**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve it as follows:

```
this.$route.params.id
```